# Python: Take a list of filenames and convert them to a specific format

Tags: python, emoji, slack

I have a large list of filenames that I'd like to convert to a specific format.

e.g.

```
"D:\emote\aaatoot.gif"
"D:\emote\aatrek.001.gif"
"D:\emote\agesilaus.001.png"
"D:\emote\agreed.001.png"
"D:\emote\anarchists.001.gif"
etc...
```

into

```
emojis:
  - name: aaatoot
    src: D:\emote\aaatoot.gif
  - name: aatrek.001.gif
    src: D:\emote\aatrek.001.gif.gif
etc...
```

I'm trying to turn a folder of images into an [emojipack](https://github.com/lambtron/emojipacks#emoji-yaml-file) which will be imported into slack, if that's relevant.
Any help would be great.

Comment: from where `aaatoot.001` came???

Comment: do you need to do that in python? I would use Sublime Text 3...

Comment: @Hackaholic, sorry about that, that was a mistake, I edited my question.

Comment: @Francesco, no I do not need to use python, it's just what I am most familiar with, I'll look into sublime text 3

Comment: Why does `name: agesilaus.001` have `src: D:\emote\aatrek.001.gif`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read the file and format like this:

```
import os
with open("your_file") as f, open("new_file", "w") as f1:
    f1.write("Emojis:\n")
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        name = os.path.basename(line)
        f1.write("\t- name: {}\n\t  src:{}\n".format(name, line))
```